# Javascript: get children by tag type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where the server-side is producing resultant HTML of the form:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <ul>
        <li class="imageElem">
            <img src="..."/>
            <div id="imgInfo">
                <p class="imgDetail">
                    Image Title #1
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>

        <!-- Etc. for many images (1 <li> per <img>) -->

    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to loop through this list and perform on-the-fly DOM manipulation with jQuery. I'm running into three bottlenecks:

- How to obtain `myDiv`'s single `<ul>` child that has neither an `id` or `class` (and to change the server-side code to produce one of these will be a **nightmare**); and
- How to obtain each `<li>`'s single `<img>` child; same as above for getting the server to generates id/class attributes; and
- How to obtain each `<li>`'s single `<p>` child's text (e.g. "Image Title #1")

I am trying the following (for each of those three issues respectively) to no avail:

```
var myDivUL = document.getElementById("myDiv").ul;
for(i = 0; i < myDivUL.length; i++)
{
    var currImageElem = myDivUL[i].img;
    var currPText = myDiv[i].div.p.text;

    // ... rest of function omitted for brevity
}
```

**What am I doing wrong here?** What doe I need to change to get the three elements without having access to id/class attributes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to find the `img`, and text of the `p`, child of the `li` that has no `class`, and no `id`? Does the `img` *also* have neither `id` nor `class`? I'm confused by your *same as above...*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get all things like this:

```
$("#myDiv").find("ul:not([id],[class])").each(function()
{
    $(this).find("li").each(function(){
       var IMG = $(this).find("img:not([id],[class])");
       var PText = $(this).find("p.imgDetail").text();
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I interact with this piece of code though? Meaning, how would I then iterate through each `<li>` and ask it for its `<img>` and `<p>` children?

Comment: This function already iterating through all UL tags from Div and all LI tags from particular UL. You can find your image in var "IMG" and text of p tag in "PText".

Comment: Thanks again, but still confused (maybe you could update your answer to show an example?). What if I wanted to access the 3rd <li>'s IMG field? How would I get it?

Comment: See this JSFiddle Link.     
http://jsfiddle.net/rLLGB/3/

Please tell if u want only third li's p tag text?

Answer (score 19):

You can do something like this

```
var myDivUL = document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
```

& so on, the key is to use **getElementsByTagName() on any html element**.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ul = $('#myDiv ul').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).attr('id') && !$(this).attr('class');
});
var img = $('li > img', ul); // will give li > img child of the "ul" 
var pText = $('li p', ul).text();
```

Comment: Thanks - can you confirm that `$('li img', ul);` translates to: "Give me the li > img child of the "ul" element?

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of tips:

1. `getElementById()` returns a single value, not an array, because IDs are supposed to be unique.
2. You should verify how your browser handles duplicate IDs when fixing invalid HTML. Firebug's DOM tree or your browser's equivalent may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like

```
$("ul:not([id], [class])").each(function() {
      var img = $(this).find("img");
      var p = $(this).find("p.imgDetail");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- `myDiv`'s single `<ul>` child that has neither an `id` or `class`

  ```
  $("#myDiv li:not([class]):not([id])")
  ```
- obtain each `<li>`'s single `<img>` child

  ```
  $("#myDiv li:not([class]):not([id]) img")
  ```
- obtain each `<li>`'s single `<p>` child's text

  ```
  $("#myDiv li:not([class]):not([id]) p")
  ```

You can loop through the result with `.each()` to get your stuffs

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd implement this is:

```
$('ul li').filter(
    function(){
        return !this.id && !this.className;
    }).find('img, p').each(
        function(){
            if ($(this).is('img')){
                imgs.push($(this));
                // or console.log($(this));
                // or anything else, really...
            }
            else if ($(this).is('p')){
                pText.push($(this).text());
                // or console.log($(this));
                // or anything else, really...
            }
        });
```

[JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nesk5/).